# Accessing class variables using a variable with the class name in perl

Tags: perl, oop, class-variables

I'm wondering how I would go about doing this:

```
package Something;
our $secret = "blah";

sub get_secret {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return; # I want to return the secret variable here
}
```

Now when I go

```
print Something->get_secret();
```

I want it to print `blah`. Now before you tell me to just use `$secret`, I want to make sure that if a derived class uses `Something` as base, and I call `get_secret` I should get that class' secret.

How do you reference the package variable using `$class`? I know I can use `eval` but is there more elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `$secret` supposed to be modifiable within the package? If not, you can get rid of the variable and instead just have a class method return the value. Classes that want to have a different secret would then override the method, instead of changing the value of the secret. E.g.:

```
package Something;

use warnings; use strict;

use constant get_secret => 'blah';

package SomethingElse;

use warnings; use strict;

use base 'Something';

use constant get_secret => 'meh';

package SomethingOther;

use warnings; use strict;

use base 'Something';

package main;

use warnings; use strict;

print SomethingElse->get_secret, "\n";
print SomethingOther->get_secret, "\n";
```

Otherwise, [perltooc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltooc.html) contains useful techniques to fit a variety of scenarios. `perltooc` points to [Class::Data::Inheritable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::Data::Inheritable) which looks like it would fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references):

```
no strict 'refs';
return ${"${class}::secret"};
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, unfortunately our code has to `use strict`. Is there another way to reference it?

Comment: @Gaurav, why can't you turn off strict for that one line?

Comment: @cjm Yes, I can turn it off for a line, but then it's just as un-elegant as using `eval`, and takes up 2 more LoC. :)

Comment: @Gaurav-Dadhania: `no strict 'refs'` is clearer. Once you've seen this construct, you'll never mistake it for anything else. `eval` only means that you have to parse more Perl by hand.

Comment: turning off `strict 'refs'` is MUCH safer than a string eval.  `strict` is a tool that you use to avoid errors, there is nothing wrong with turning it of for a few lines if you know you have to.  `strict` is there to help, not to get in your way or limit the power of the language